# show article ID in URL when link is active

Tags: php, sql, url, get

I have a newspage where every article is being showed by a SQL while loop
the date and title is visible but to read more you have to click a a href and the accordion
slides down and the article will be visible.
what i'm trying to reach is that when you click on the read more, the article ID is shown/passed to the url.

So this i have now:`index.php?pagina=nieuws`

This is what i'm trying to reach:
`index.php?pagina=nieuws#id=25` or so

Don't know what to change or to add so an example would be helpful

```
require_once("...");
mysql_select_db("...");
$query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
echo $_GET["id"];
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.acc_containernieuws').hide(); 
$('.acc_triggernieuws').click(function(){
if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
    $('.acc_triggernieuws').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
}
return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

});

while(list($id,$datum,$titel,$artikel) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo("<div id=\"artikeltitel\" align=\"center\">
<div id=\"containerdatum\">$datum</div>
<div id=\"containertitel\">$titel</div>
<div id=\"container3\" style=\"font-size:12px;\"></div>
</div>
<div class=\"containernieuws\" align=\"center\">
<h2 class=\"acc_triggernieuws\"><a href=\"#?id=$id\"> Meer weergeven </a></h2>
<div class=\"acc_containernieuws\">
<div class=\"blocknieuws\">$artikel</div>
<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"\" data-num-    posts=\"10\" data-width=\"678\"></div>
</div>
</div>
");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A #id=25 is only a link to an element in the current page. Of course, if you use AJAX or JQuery, you can intercept this and add more data, but to start with, is by using a normal parameter, eg ?pagina=nieuws&from_id=25 where you specify the new start-location of the news items. This will be a full new web_page request where you can display the new/extra content. (eg just like a 'next' page link).

You'll need to modify your SQL string to include this parameter.

Be sure to use proper SQL Escapes (mysql_real_escaped_string) eg in order to prevent SQL Injections

Eg:

```
if (isset($_GET['from_id']))
    $query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws WHERE id > '".mysql_real_escaped_string($_GET['from_id'])."' ORDER BY id DESC";
else
    $query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Jelle you gonna have to explain in some simple language :-) i know just enough php to make my form and the while loop thing, but don't quit understand what you're suggesting, i changed my $query in to your example but it didn't help me alot..?

Comment: and indeed the $(currentAnchor).show(); did the job!